# Is it possible to add a custom message to a Facebook "Like" post targeting a URL outside of my domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Consider a list of URLs on a page (e.g. `example.com`), which target another domain (e.g. `domain.com`).

Is it possible to create Facebook Like buttons for each URL that would add a message to a Like post in the user's timeline, e.g. `"Found on example.com"`, while still linking to the original URL on `domain.com`?

Answer (score 3):

As @miken32 suggested. A direct method wouldn't be possible. To achieve the result you can do this...

We use [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to receive a callback whenever someone likes something via an embedded like button on your page. The syntax would be:

```
// callback that logs arguments
var page_like_callback = function(url, html_element) {
  console.log("page_like_callback");
  console.log(url);
  console.log(html_element);
}

// In your onload handler add this call
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_callback);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', page_unlike_callback);
```

Inside the CallBack function, Use this code to post your desired URL using [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'link to domain.com',
  caption: 'Found on example.com',
}, function(response){});
```

OR

**UPDATE**:

Using [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui) Dialogue Box will appear for the user to confirm the action. If that is undesirable use [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/). This would need you to specify 'publish_stream' permission

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'Found on example.com';
params['name'] = 'Heading';
params['description'] = 'Description, if needed';
params['link'] = 'domain.com';
params['picture'] = 'Images if needed';
params['caption'] = 'Found on example.com';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
  }
});

 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

Finally it would be something like this

```
// callback that logs arguments
var page_like_callback = function(url, html_element) {
  FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   link: 'link to domain.com',
   caption: 'Found on example.com',
  }, function(response){});
}
```

or better one this

```
var page_like_callback = function(url, html_element) {
 var params = {};
 params['message'] = 'Found on example.com';
 params['name'] = 'Heading';
 params['description'] = 'Description, if needed';
 params['link'] = 'domain.com';
 params['picture'] = 'Images if needed';
 params['caption'] = 'Found on example.com';

 FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
     alert('Error occured');
   } else {
     alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
   }
 });
}
```

Also,

```
 // In your onload handler add this call
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_callback);
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', page_unlike_callback);

     FB.login(function(response) {
       // handle the response
     }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm this? Can't this be used to substitute the page that someone tried to like? Looks very exciting BTW.

Comment: This should work.. I mean it is what your app does. At the time of login facebook will ask your user for granting posting rights to your app on your behalf. If only the user allows it, you can do it. If you start to spam. What would the user do. Revoke the permission and Never use your app. Sounds Fair Enough.. And Happy Coding and waiting for the bounty.. :P@exizt

Comment: This won't be a "like", though? Using the default "Like" button isn't possible with this solution, is it?

Comment: For your second question. Sadly, no. And for the first one. Yes. it is. Cause only when you click on like button page_like_callback will called and when that happens the code for posting your link is done. Please refer to the mentioned links for having a in-depth idea.

Comment: What this answer does is let the user like the page, and then prompts user with the ["post to newsfeed" dialog](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer%2F)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the prompt. I made an update for removing the prompt screen and the output will be exact as you needed.
@miken32

Comment: See Update.. @exizt. A prompt screen will appear if you use FB.ui() whilst using FB.api() it wont.

Comment: I think there's some trouble with formatting in your post now. Could you try to fix it?

Comment: @exizt After a long time, my path crossed across the post. I have done the formatting as you suggested. I was new to SO then I guess.. :P. Cheers.:)